# Cell Fracture Exploding When I Add Rigid Body

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, cell-fracture

It keeps exploding and idk why, pls help.

Here's the file https://we.tl/t-cjMKbH7rsG

Comment: OK it drives me crazy :) There are two things that give a reason to cause explosion - you can't use Collision Shape > Convex here, but Mesh instead and if you enable Face orientation overlay many of charts highlights red faces because of bad topology, that can confuse blender to say what is in and out for sim. But even I tried to ... Apply Scale, lower Sensitivity Margin, keep only two nice looking shards, delete Rigid Body World and create a new one ... it is still exploding. I'm quit ... sorry.

Comment: It might be the topology of the shards. I did a *Merge By Distance* for several shards and it always removed some vertices. So I added a *Remesh* modifier (mode *Sharp*), applied the *Scale*, transferred the modifier to all shards (menu *Object > Link/Transfer Data > Copy Modifiers*) and applied it (*Object > Convert > Mesh*). Then deleted the Rigid World and made all shards Rigid bodies again (*Object > Rigid Body > Add Active*). Then it no longer exploded but just crumbled apart. Unfortunately, you see cracks. But you can swap a solid object with the fragments for animation.

Comment: To stop the crumble you can use Rigid constraints (*Object > Rigid Body > Connect* IIRC) or start them deactivated (*Physics Properties* tab *> Rigid Body > Dynamics > [X] Deactivation > [X] Start Deactivated*. You need to keyframe a collision to blow it up. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR9SZ.gif (start deactivated) -- oh, and changed the *Collision Shape* to *Mesh* like *vklidu* wrote!